# Append columns to existing CSV file in HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

I am trying to append columns to a existing CSV file in HDFS.

Script1:

```
someDF1.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").mode("append").option("sep", "\t").option("header","true").save("folder/test_file.csv")
```

Error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Parent path is not a directory.
```

Any suggestions on the mistake would be helpful

Comment: you need to read it, transform it with new column and then write it back with `.mode("overwrite")`

Comment: @ChitralVerma could you please explain it little further.

Comment: Hadoop doesn't allow appends. You need to read the file, update the data with new data, then add overwrite() method before you save() to a *directory*, not a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV files doesn't support Schema Evolution. So basically what you have to do is to read the entire data in the target path and then add the new column in this dataframe with some default value.

```
val oldDF = dfWithExistingData.withColumn("new_col", lit(null))
```

You can then union or merge this dataframe with the new dataset.

```
val targetData = oldDF.union(newDF)
```

You can then write the Data back to your target path in overwrite mode.

```
targetData
.repartition(1)
.write
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.mode("overwrite")
.option("sep", "\t")
.option("header","true")
.save("folder")
```

**Alternative**: You can switch to other file formats which supports schema evolution e.g: Parquet to avoid doing the above process.